# this + class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I have three input fields. When one has text in it, an anchor will show to the right. Currently though, when I type in one, the anchor will appear for all three input fields.

What I need to know is, is there a this + class selector for jQuery? For example:
`$(this + '.more')`

This is something I need right now and I can't seem to find it or anything similar in the jQuery API.

HTML:

```
<div id="max">

  <span class="sub title">Max</span>
  <input type="text" /><a class="more" href="" onclick="">...more</a>

</div><div id="onepoint">

  <span class="sub title">One Point</span>
  <input type="text" /><a class="more" href="" onclick="">...more</a>

</div><div id="leftover">

  <span class="sub title">Leftover</span>
  <input type="text" /><a class="more" href="" onclick="">...more</a>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#max input[type=text], #onepoint input[type=text], #leftover input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
  if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
    $('.more').hide();
  } else {
    $('.more').show();
  }
});
```

If I have the selector as just `$('.more')` all three toggle when I only want the right one too. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the next sibling of the changed `input` element so use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next) and to change the display use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) instead of show/hide

```
$('#max input[type=text], #onepoint input[type=text], #leftover input[type=text]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).next('.more').toggle($(this).val() != '');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next()` to target the next element after the input

```
$('input[type=text]', '#max, #onepoint, #leftover').on('change', function() {
    $(this).next('.more').toggle( !!this.value.length );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TTFrT/)

Comment: @RGS Both are needed otherwise it's inverted from what I want. When the field is empty, `.more` should be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally suggest amending your initial selector to:

```
$('div[id] > input[type="text"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this).next('a').toggle(this.value.length);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7722d/).

Or, to use specific elements' `id`s as identifiers (but still shorten the selector chain a little):

```
$('#max, #onepoint, #leftover').find('input[type="text"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this).next('a').toggle(this.value.length);
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7722d/1/).

Reference:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: This isn't the only instance of inputs in divs. If it was I'd use it.

Comment: Yes, that should work but now it's the same as the other answers :P

Comment: I prefer using more specific selectors, so as you said, it's all personal taste. Thanks for the answer nonetheless.